# Selecting 8 bit planes using Matlab's bitget(). Show the 8 bit planes?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to make this code work but I can't figure out the problem...

```
img = imread('cameraman.tif');

for i = 1:8
    a{i}=bitget(img,i);
    subplot(2,4,i), imshow(logical(a{i})), title('Bit plane');
end
```

the output error is

```
Unable to perform assignment because brace indexing is not supported for variables of this type.
    Error in (line 15)
        a{i}=bitget(img,i);
```

Do you see where's the problem? Thanks

Comment: If I copy and paste your code, it works as expected without errors. Since the error message states that the error occurs in line 15, but your example code only has 6 lines, the part that causes the error seems to be missing. Try to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I just pasted the 'working' extract, real lines from 1 to 8 are just comments, so the actual line 15 is a{i}=bitget(img,i);

Comment: Interestingly I got the error when I run it once. Running it again made it work, even clearing the workspace

Comment: @AmosCappellaro Try `clear a` before you run the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that `a` does not support brace indexing. This means that, before you ran your code, `a` was already defined.

To write robust code, you should always initialize all your variables. In this case, write `a = {};` before the loop. This will ensure `a` is of the right type.

Even better is to pre-allocate `a` to have the right size, so it doesn’t get resized every loop iteration:

```
a = cell(8,1);
```

Comment: It works just perfect now, didn't think about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I worked on having **8 bit planes** using **MATLAB** and here is my code for your reference :)[image]

```
row=512;  col=512;
file_raw = 'tif.raw';
fin=fopen(file_raw,'r');
I=fread(fin,row*col,'uint8=>uint8'); 
Z=reshape(I,row,col);
Z=Z';
fclose(fin);
figure('Name',file_raw,'NumberTitle','off');
subplot(3,3,1);
imshow(Z);
title(file_raw)  

B=zeros(size(I));
B1=bitset(B,1,bitget(I,1));
B2=bitset(B,2,bitget(I,2));
B3=bitset(B,3,bitget(I,3));
B4=bitset(B,4,bitget(I,4));
B5=bitset(B,5,bitget(I,5));
B6=bitset(B,6,bitget(I,6));
B7=bitset(B,7,bitget(I,7));
B8=bitset(B,8,bitget(I,8));
B = B1+B2+B3+B4+B5+B6+B7+B8;
B=uint8(B);
Br=reshape(B,row,col);
Br=Br';
subplot(3,3,2);
imshow(Br);
title('reconstruct');

C=255*bitget(I,5);
C=uint8(C);
Cr=reshape(C,row,col);
Cr=Cr';
subplot(3,3,3);
imshow(Cr);
title('bitget 5');

D=255*bitget(I, 8);
D=uint8(D);
Dr=reshape(D,row,col);
Dr=Dr';
subplot(3,3,4);
imshow(Dr);
title('bitget 8');

file_bprint = 'bprint7.raw';
fin=fopen(file_bprint,'r');
I=fread(fin,row*col,'uint8=>uint8'); 
E=reshape(I,row,col);
E=E';
fclose(fin);
subplot(3,3,5);
imshow(E);
title(file_bprint);
```